# seleniumpython dropdown list div

Tags: python, selenium

i whould like to select the element "aout" for example on the folloing dropdown list with python selenium

```html
<div class="questionDropdownContainer inlineBlock isActive" id="dob2_m">
                    <span class="questionDropdownPlaceholder" data-val="3" id="dateMonth" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">mars</span>
                    <span class="iconDropdown inlineBlock valignMiddle"></span>

                    <div class="questionDropdownOptions ps-container ps-active-x ps-active-y isActiveSurveyDropDown" style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="1">janvier</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="2">février</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month selected" data-id="3">mars</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="4">avril</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="5">mai</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="6">juin</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="7">juillet</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="8">août</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="9">septembre</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="10">octobre</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="11">novembre</span>
                        <span class="option-1-month" data-id="12">décembre</span>
                    <div class="ps-scrollbar-x-rail" style="width: 120px; left: 0px; bottom: 3px;"><div class="ps-scrollbar-x" style="left: 0px; width: 110px;"></div></div><div class="ps-scrollbar-y-rail" style="top: 0px; height: 234px; right: 3px;"><div class="ps-scrollbar-y" style="top: 0px; height: 116px;"></div></div></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="date_m" value="4">
                </div>
```

When I try this code…

```
driver.find_element_by_id("dob2_m").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("dob2_m").find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-id="8"]').click()
```

I get this error…
[error script picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bWe0.png)
How to do it ?
Help me please
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error snippet clearly says the error occurs when webdriver tries to interact with element with class="option-1-day". But this element is not present in the code you have shared. So i assume, you are facing issue while trying to select date from dropdown.

1.Before clicking dropdown element, try to add wait statement

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

2. It will occur when the webelement you trying to click, located at end of dropdown. So it can only clickable once scrolling it down.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what is the class Action, i have this error when i use your lines : C:\Users\matth\Desktop\money>python test.py
  File "test.py", line 12
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use select class  for handling  dropdown.

s1= Select(driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_your_element'))//in this case it would be dob2_m

s1.select_by_visible_text('janvier')

Ignore formatting  using mobile to answer.

Option 2

Use javascriptexecutor to scroll and click on element

ele= self.web_driver.find_element_by_xpath('SOME_XPATH')

coordinates = ele.location_once_scrolled_into_view

self.web_driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({}, {});'.format(coordinates['x'], coordinates

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunatly it only works for <select> element not <div>

Comment: Try to use javascriptexecutor  to scroll and click.updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ActionChains`.
When you call methods for actions on the ActionChains object, the actions are stored in a queue in the ActionChains object. When you call perform(), the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

[More information](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html).

Here is an example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


...#navigate to page
el=driver.find_element_by_id("bxFormPesquisa") #here I get the dropdown element
ActionChains(driver).click(el).perform()
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('bxFormPesquisa')) #again
select.select_by_visible_text('AL') #it is the text in dropdown list
#dropdown should be selected with value from line above
```

Comment: I didn't understand well how i should use it for my problem. first line, i get the dropdown list by its id, second line elements of the list are stored in a queue, but how should i used the 2 last lines ? Select() is only for <select> element